# Zipping together entries of a list of lists using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a list with multiple lists (for simplicity 3, but I actually have a very large amount):

```
list = [[1,a,2],[3,b,4],[5,c,6]]
```

How do I obtain a new lists of lists that combines the original list items based on their positions using Python?

```
new_list = [[1,3,5],[a,b,c],[2,4,6]]
```

I've been trying the zip function on "list" but it's not working, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to show what you actually tried, and give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: Additionally it would be nice to see what you tried with the `zip()` function, so that other users can learn from the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want.

```python
mylist = [[1,"a",2],[3,"b",4],[5,"c",6]]
mylist2 = list(map(list, zip(*mylist)))
```

Please don't use list, or any other [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) as variable name.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P7cyJ7O4RMFWITraUEcpUUnHKFYn2lhHKUlJxwTIMtVRSlbSMYuN5YIoNAKqBNEauYkFGiCGjkJVZoGGFkRWU1OTi6ugKDMPKA8RQOEZaf7/DwA)

```python
list(map(list, zip(*mylist)))

                   *mylist    -- unpacks the list
               zip(*mylist)   -- creates an iterable of the unpacked list, 
                                 with the i-th element beeing a tuple 
                                 containing all i-th elements of each element of *mylist
         list                 -- Is the built-in function list()
     map( f  ,   iter      )  -- Applys a function f to all elements of an iterable iter
list(                       ) -- Creates a list from whatever is inside.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use zip:

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
l = [[1,a,2],[3,b,4],[5,c,6]]

new_l = list(map(list, zip(*l)))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 5], [1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Notice that the variables are now displayed in the second element of `new_l`

Comment: This will not work as intended in python 3.x. `map(..)` is still a map object. A list object must be created by `list(map(..))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip), also keep in minde it's bad practice to use [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) as variable name.

```
l = [[1,a,2],[3,b,4],[5,c,6]]
list(zip(*l))
```

output

```
[[1,3,5],[a,b,c],[2,4,6]]
```

Comment: `list` is not a keyword, technically speaking.

Comment: @Coldspeed it is not technically, but i don't know another word for it in english. : )

Comment: `list` is a builtin class. That's enough ;)